# Java - concatenar números y texto con diferentes métodos

Tags: java

Quiero crear una serie de métodos para conseguir lo siguiente:

- El método `createReference` asigna al atributo `reference` el valor que en ese momento tiene `referenceId` concatenándole por delante el String "PROD."
- Una vez asignado el valor al atributo `reference`, el valor de `referenceId` se tiene que incrementar una unidad.

*Por ejemplo, si `referenceId` es igual a 15005, entonces el `reference` del objeto que estamos instanciando tendrá el valor "PROD.15005"*

De momento lo que he creado son los métodos que generan el incremento de la unidad y creo que es correcto

```
/**
*  Getter of "reference"
*/
public String getReference() {
    return reference;
}

/**
* Setter of "referenceId". It assigns "nextId" value to "referenceId" and increases "nextReferenceId" by using "incNextReferenceId()".
*/
private void CreateReference() {
    this.reference = "PROD." + getNextReference();
    incNextReference();
}

/**
* Getter of "nextReferenceId"
* @return nextReferenceId's value
*/
public int getNextReference() {
    return referenceId;
}

/**
* Increases one unit the value of "nextReferenceId"
*/
private void incNextReference(){
referenceId++;
}
```

No tengo ningún test específico para este punto, sólo lo siguiente:

```
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
class ProductTest {

    Product product1;
    @Test
    @Order(1)
    void testReference() {
        assertEquals("PROD.15000", product1.getReference());    
        assertEquals("PROD.15001", product2.getReference());
    }
```

Gracias.

Comment: Esto ya es cuestión de interpretación... Tal como yo lo veo, por lo que dice en la descripción del método `createReference()` lo que yo haría es modificar la lógica de ese método como sigue: `this.reference = "PROD." + getReferenceId();`, puesto que de la manera en que lo haces, no estás añadiendo el "PROD." en tu método, si no en el getter... imagínate que luego necesitas obtener la siguiente referencia numérica para hacer alguna comprobación tendrás un problema porque no te devolverá el número, si no la concatenación con el texto! Además, tu método `getReferenceId` es tipo int, no String!

Comment: @Benito-B, muchas gracias! Por eso no estaba seguro de que mi propuesta fuera la adecuada. Quería poder añadirlo sólo al final y así poder mantener la parte numérica! Voy a probarlo! Gracias

Comment: @Benito-B, he editado la pregunta porque sigue fallando. No hace la suma y no entiendo por qué la verdad...

Comment: @IñigoCatalánEchave el error te lo da con la concatenacion?

Comment: @David, el error me lo da al no hacer la suma +1 ud. El test 2 espera que el valor sea ```15001``` pero llega un valor de ```15000```.

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]

Comment: @RuslanLópez, no soy capaz de plantear la consulta de otra forma. El comportamiento esperado está indicado en los test, el problema se indica y el código inicial también. Te agradecería que me dijeras cómo plantearías la pregunta si no te parece adecuada mi forma de plantearla. Gracias

Comment: no tienes una clase, no pusiste el mensaje de error de los test cases, no pusiste la versión de java ni de junit ( que yo asumo que es la 5 ), no pusiste si tu clase tiene constructores, etc.

Comment: @RuslanLópez, creo que muchas de las cosas que indicas no son necesarias. El error es que no me hace la suma a partir de los métodos que indico ymi clase tiene un constructor pero no es para estos métodos que muestro por lo que no creo que sea necesario añadirlo. La clase tiene bastantes más líneas de código y no creo que deba añadir tanta información porque no aporta.